# jQuery toggle, close link is not swapping toggle status

Tags: jquery

hello so i have the following:

```
jQuery('#settings').toggle(function() {
  jQuery('#event_time_interval_form_part').fadeIn();
}, function() {
  jQuery('#event_time_interval_form_part').fadeOut();
});
jQuery('.cancel').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery(this).parents('#event_time_interval_form_part').fadeOut();
});
```

and the HTML

```
<div class="auction-settings">
    <span id="settings"><span class="icon icon-cogs"></span> settings</span>
    <div id="event_time_interval_form_part" style="display:none;" >
        <span class="cancel">cancel</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

However i cannot work out how to switch the toggle around when you click the close link, the toggle works time when you click on settings (opens and closes) but w hen it is open and you click cancel inside the toggle area, it closes which is good but if you click settings again you have to click it twice before it shows.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is your `.actions .cancel` button where you have written `content` in your above code?

Comment: I have just updated, its where content was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`toggle` event method is deprecated. You can use `click` and `fadeToggle` methods instead:

```
$('#settings, .cancel').click(function(e) {
    $('#event_time_interval_form_part').fadeToggle();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RmFfz/

Note that `span` click Event doesn't have any default action, there is no need to use `preventDefault()` method.

Comment: Ahh worked great! thanks for the solution, very simple! thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `.toggle` use `.click` see http://jsfiddle.net/AUz97/3/

```
jQuery('#settings').click(function() {
  jQuery('#event_time_interval_form_part').toggle();

});
jQuery('.cancel').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery(this).parents('#event_time_interval_form_part').fadeOut()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

fiddled: http://jsfiddle.net/AUz97/

But

```
jQuery('.actions .cancel').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery(this).parents('#event_time_interval_form_part').fadeOut();
});
```

where are these classes .action .cancel added to an element where u can click on?

Comment: i update your jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/AUz97/1/ you will see if you click on settings then cancel then settings again you have to click settings twice for it to appear again.

Comment: Yepp, seen. Usually, toggle should consider the current state of `display:` but obviously its doesn't. I tend to regard this a jQuery issue, although I have seen only very few in the wild. This needs to be debugged on DOM level to see where the settings/changes are actually going.

Comment: Actually, after closing by clicking on "cancel" the state is the same as after initialization, but the first click after that on setting doens't change anything. Second click works as expected. clueless ...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery < 1.9 then

```
jQuery('#settings').toggle(function() {
    jQuery('#event_time_interval_form_part').fadeIn();
}, function() {
    jQuery('#event_time_interval_form_part').fadeOut();
});
jQuery('.cancel').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery('#settings').click()
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/eSzwa/)